# Why we cannot use current instance members in closure?

Tags: ios, swift

```
struct Account
{
    var aName:String
    var aType:String
    var aNo:Int
    
    init(aName: String, aType: String, aNo: Int) {
        self.aName = aName
        self.aType = aType
        self.aNo = aNo
    }
    /*
    func display()
    {
        print("AccountName:\(aName) AccountType:\(aType)  AccountNumber:\(aNo)")
    }
    */
     var display = {
        print("AccountName:\(aName) AccountType:\(aType) AccountNumber:\(aNo)")    }
}
```

If swift functions and closure are same. then why we cannot use instance members in closure ?

Comment: That is not a valid syntax, what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: May be you just want `var display: String { print("AccountName:\(aName) AccountType:\(aType) AccountNumber:\(aNo)") }`

Comment: @D.Mika that will not compile, the code must return a string.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: Ja, sure, you're right. I forgot to remove the print statement. It should have been `var display: String { "AccountName:\(aName) AccountType:\(aType) AccountNumber:\(aNo)" }`

Answer (score 0):

The error message I see in a Playground is:

> Instance member 'aName' cannot be used on type 'Account'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

That’s pretty confusing.

Ordinarily you can refer to properties in a closure. The problem in this specific example is that you are trying to initialise a property in `Account` with a closure that refers to other properties. You cannot reference the properties of an object until it has been fully initialised. By making the property lazy its initialisation is deferred until the first time it is used, by which time the other properties will be initialised and you can refer to them in the closure:

```
struct Account
{
    var aName:String
    var aType:String
    var aNo:Int
    
    init(aName: String, aType: String, aNo: Int) {
        self.aName = aName
        self.aType = aType
        self.aNo = aNo
    }
    /*
    func display()
    {
        print("AccountName:\(aName) AccountType:\(aType)  AccountNumber:\(aNo)")
    }
    */
    lazy var display = {
        print("AccountName:\(aName) AccountType:\(aType) AccountNumber:\(aNo)")   
    }

}
```

If the closure was declared in a different context then it would work fine as seen in this example:

```
struct Account
{
    var aName:String
    var aType:String
    var aNo:Int
    
    init(aName: String, aType: String, aNo: Int) {
        self.aName = aName
        self.aType = aType
        self.aNo = aNo
    }
    
    func printDesription() {
        let display = {
            print("AccountName:\(aName) AccountType:\(aType) AccountNumber:\(aNo)")
        }
        
        display()
    }
}

let account = Account(aName: "name", aType: "type", aNo: 42)
account.printDesription()
```

Which produces this output:

```
AccountName:name AccountType:type AccountNumber:42
```